# Can't overload the = assignment operator in derived class (as I want); call from main jumps to base class operator method

Tags: c++, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to implement a class for a matrix with all the usual operations, just as an exercise. I implemented the common operations (+, -, ·) but my problem came when I tried to implement slicing operations—similar to Numpy. For example, if I want to make something like `a[2:5,1:3] = b[10:13, 10:12]` I concluded that I would need some kind of ‘smart iterator’ (I don't know the technical name) that detect how to move one row down. I have two classes:

- `MatrixIterator`: A base class with a pointer and indexes to the sub-matrix they represent (could be the whole matrix).
- `Matrix`: The derived class of `MatrixIterator`, which has almost the same operators inherited, with the difference that in the constructor and deconstructor is allocated and released the part of the memory which contains the matrix array.

The problem arose when I realized that the `=` assignment operator should be different for both classes. Because If I want to make something like `a = b`, then I should just destroy the allocated array in `a` and make a ‘re-initialization’ with the data of `b` (in case the dimensions changed); which, as I understood, must be ‘manually’ done. But with `a[2:5,1:3] = b[10:13, 10:12]`, I just assign element to element without a ‘re-initialization’.

I ended up with something like

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>

//Base class
template <class T>
class MatrixIterator
{
    public:
        MatrixIterator<T>();
        MatrixIterator<T>& operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b);
};

//Derived class
template <class T>
class Matrix : public MatrixIterator<T>
{
    using base = MatrixIterator<T>;
    public:
        Matrix<T>();
        Matrix<T>& operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b);
};

template <class T>
MatrixIterator<T>::MatrixIterator()
{
}

template <class T>
MatrixIterator<T>& MatrixIterator<T>::operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b)
{
    std::cout << "Base class method called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b)
{
    std::cout << "Derived class method called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> a;
    Matrix<int> c;
    c = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs `Base class method called`.

**Problem**: When I do `c = a`, the program jumps to the base class `MatrixIterator` `=` method, while I'm expecting that it jump to the derived class `Matrix` method, becuse `a` was declared as such.

So, I changed the prototype of the function from `Matrix<T>& operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b);` to `Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& b)` and... it works fine. But I don't want that because I want to implement the `=` operator with the right operand understood in a broader sense; for it could be either a Matrix (`a = b`) or a MatrixIterator (`a = b[10:13, 10:12]`), both assignments requiring the left operand to be ‘re-initialized’.

I could write four methods for the four combinations of the `=` operator (`Matrix = Matrix`, `Matrix = MatrixIterator`, `MatrixIterator = Matrix`, `MatrixIterator = MatrixIterator`). But I'm too lazy for doing that. Actually, the whole point in creating the `MatrixIterator` as a base class and defining almost all the operators in that class was with the purpose of avoiding to rewrite the implementation of every operator four times.

So: If somebody understands what I'm trying to do, is there a way to make the compiler understand me? Does it worth it? Or would you say that my implementation of a base class as iterator is a poor , naïf, weak-minded strategy? Don't hesitate, say whatever you think.

Comment: You could add the missing assignment back in: `Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& b) = default;`

Comment: Side note: [Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301). That's not what it is for, and it's practically asking for problems. Use `<cassert>` instead.

Comment: @Eljay `error: definition of explicitly-defaulted ‘Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T>&)’ ` , could you explain a little more please?

Comment: Side note: Turn on the address sanitizer for additional diagnostic information: https://godbolt.org/z/4fP7azf9P In the link I've turned on address and undefined behaviour sanitizers, and address sanitizer trips over a significant error and gives a wonderful error report.

Comment: Regarding the error you got with Eljay's recommended change, I suspect you left the function implementation in the code. If you default the function, you don't need  the implementation. The compiler makes it for you. End result, compiler sees the default request and makes the function, then finds the implementation later in the code and thinks, "Oh bother. Now I have two implementations. What to do?"

Comment: A side note about assignment operators: Take a look at [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) It describes a nearly-fool proof way to write assignment operators. It's not always the most efficient, but A) it gets you going and B) profiling will tell you if you need to do something smarter. I pretty much always start with Copy and Swap when I need to write an assignment operator and very rarely do I have to migrate away from it.

Comment: And [the X-Y solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Use a `std::vector` to manage the dynamic array, if possible, and eliminate the need for special member functions. [The Rule of Zero kicks ass](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @user4581301 If I default the function (without my definition), then it keeps jumping to base class method. I'm starting to think whether there's a better strategy because a matrix isn't an iterator but I'm implementing as such

Comment: Recommendation: It looks like what you are trying to make is a 2D range, not an iterator. At it's simplest the range is only a view into the matrix and will hold a pointer to the matrix data, a row and column offset (the starting point) and the ranges number of rows and columns . Iterator or range, inheritance isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: Readability note: `size_t m; //ranks` When you have a simple comment like this explaining what the variable represents, consider changing the name of the variable so that the comment is unnecessary. Eg: `size_t ranks;`. Now everyone reading the code knows exactly what the identifier represents anywhere in the code, not just up at the definition. Yeah, you do a bit more typing, but the time spent writing  a program is usually barely significant compared to the time spent debugging and maintaining.  Spend more time on the cheap part to make the expensive part faster and you'll come out ahead.

Comment: @user4581301 okok, I'm reading all your side notes and are useful, thanks. I'll give a better format to the code. The main problem that I'm dealing with is: I know inheritance is a bad strategy, but I can't find a better one. Because if a create a ‘range’ object with the offset and all the necessary stuff to slice the matrix, and I define all the operators between Matrix objects, my concern is that if I do `a = b[2:5,2:5]` (or rather `b(2, 5, 2, 5)`) with `b` a Matrix object, wouldn't be the destructor  of the same object called twice?

Comment: @user4581301 Do you think it's better to implement `a = b[2:5, 2:5]` passing `b[2:5, 2:5]` by value instead by reference?

Comment: the range would be passed by value, but contain references (pointers in this case because you can't easily assign a class that holds references)  to the data in the original matrix.

Comment: I'm softening to inheritance here, but with an extra layer of abstraction.  If you want to have a uniform API that doesn't know the difference between an actual matrix and a 2D range that represents a subset of a matrix, consider having a really stupid, pure virtual base class that's effectively an interface. Both the range and the matrix implement this interface.

Comment: An alternative is  to eliminate the concept of a range and have a smarter matrix constructor that builds a new matrix that is a copy of a range inside a source matrix. Only one class in this case, but a lot of copying. and you can't use the copy to modify the source, if that's an issue at all. If you want the ranges to be completely unable to affect the source, this is a viable option.

Comment: Have you taken a look at something like [armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/) either to use instead of rolling your own or to see how they solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: Given that you describe your problem as calling an `operator=()` in a way you don't expect, you can simplify your example (a lot), which will help isolate the concern, by eliminating the data members and member functions other than constructors, destructor, and assignment operators.   What the class does, and even what the assignment operators do, is not actually relevant - but distracts from the concern.

Comment: Why do you need `MatrixIterator` at all? If your full code has virtual functions in `MatrixIterator`, then *having* the assignment operator in there is a very bad idea. Normally you should disable all copying via copy assignment and copy construction in an hierarchy with virtual functions. If there are no virtual functions, then `MatrixIterator` is not usable on its own and should be integrated back into `Matrix`.

Comment: "but I can't find a better one" Perhaps you are looking for the [Pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to overload assignment `operator=(Matrix<T>)` and then delegate the task to the `operator=(MatrixIterator<T>)` as shown below.

```
//Derived class
template <class T>
class Matrix : public MatrixIterator<T>
{
    using base = MatrixIterator<T>;
    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix<T>& operator=(const MatrixIterator<T>& b);
        //ADDED THIS OVERLOAD
        Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& b)
        {
            std::cout << "Derived class Matrix parameter method called"<<std::endl;
            return (this->*static_cast<Matrix<int>& (Matrix<int>::*)(const MatrixIterator<int>&)>(&Matrix<int>::operator=))(b);//you can change this accordingly
        }
};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/46bseajh8)

Comment: Actually, I did something different: re-structured the file with two classes. One is a `"container"` which contains the variables, other is a `matrix` which contains the functions. Then defined a copy() method in `matrix` to return a container with the data copied. Then I have two implementations of `=`: `matrix = matrix ` or `matrix = container`. The first just copy the content of the pointers, the latter destroys and reconstructs the matrix with the container. So, you have to choose between `a=b` or `a=b.copy()`, similar to Python